# Can I make one C wrapper for any C++ vector that could go in a Extern C

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I need one C wrapper for any C++ vector that can be passed to a function that expects some specific type of vector.  Like my below C wrapper for OpenCV's BRISK"

```
void cv_BRISK_generateKernel(BRISK* self, vector_float* radiusList, 
vector_int* numberList, float dMax, float dMin, vector_int* indexChange) {
        self->generateKernel(*radiusList, *numberList, dMax, dMin, *indexChange);
```

}

the `vector_int*` and `vector_float*` are `typedef`'s as below

```
typedef vector<int> vector_int;
typedef vector<float> vector_float;
```

These are the vector wrappers I have so far, they work, but I would like to know if there is a way to make just one wrapper for all the vector types. It would have to go in an Extern C..so it can't be a template. but instead of having the below  wrappers I would like to make just one wrapper that can be passed to a function expecting a `vector_float*`(`typedef`for `vector<float>`) or a `vector_KeyPoint*`(`typedef` for `vector<KeyPoint>`) or a `vector_int*`(`typedef` for `vector<int>`) etc.   I know about template classes but I can't use them here because it has to go in an `extern C {}`

```
vector_float* std_create_vectorf() {
    return new vector<float>;
}
vector_int* std_create_vector() {
    return new vector<int>;
}

vector_char* std_create_vectorc() {
    return new vector<char>;
}
```

Here is my idealized wrapper If someone can help me figure out how to make this happen I would appreciate it

```
vector_any_vec* std_create_vectorany() {
    return new vector<anyvector>;
}
```

Comment: What you're looking for is basically a template class without using a template class. I really don't think that's possible. At the very least you'll end up returning a `void*`, which is considered a really bad idea.

Comment: @computerfreaker Thanks for getting back to me...are you really good at c++/c, I've searched for this answer a couple  times with no answers...and if I knew you were really knowledgeable that might help give me direction...like accept and move on etc

Comment: I'm not the best at C++, no, especially with regard to more advanced things like template classes. But the way I'm looking at your problem, you want one function capable of returning a vector of literally any datatype. This means one of two things: a template class (which still requires some level of specialization) or a `void*` return. The template class is much cleaner and safer to work with, but your `extern "C"` req makes that impossible. You technically could return a `void*` to a vector of the appropriate type, but I'm not sure how you'd tell your function what type to make the `vector`.

Answer (score 0):

How about wrapping this up in an interface using run-time polymorphism? You sacrifice a bit of type safety but it should achieve what you need.

```
enum stored_type
{
    st_int,
    st_float,
    st_char
};

struct IGeneralVector
{
    virtual stored_type get_type() = 0;
    virtual void* get_data() = 0;
    virtual ~IGeneralVector();
};

class VectorFloatHolder : public IGeneralVector
{
    std::vector<float>* data;
public:
    VectorFloatHolder(std::vector<float>* in) : data(in)
    {}
    virtual stored_type get_type() override
    {
        return st_float;
    }
    virtual void* get_data() override
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<void *>(data);
    }

    virtual ~VectorFloatHolder()
    {
        delete data;
    }
};

IGeneralVector* std_create_vectorf()
{
    return new VectorFloatHolder(new std::vector<float>);
}
```

**Update**

After reading your comment I have a slightly better idea of what you're trying to achieve. But I'm not sure whether it's possible to do exactly what you want as I'm not sure of any other implementation constraints you have. Here's another way to go this time using type erasure.

```
class ObjectHolder
{
    struct base_type
    {
        virtual ~base_type() {}
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct object_type : base_type
    {
        object_type(const T& t) : object(t) {}
        T object;
    };

    std::unique_ptr<base_type> data;
public:
    template<typename T>
    VectorHolder(T t) : data(new object_type<T>(t))
    {
    }

    template<typename T>
    T GetData()
    {
        object_type<T>* val = static_cast<object_type<T>*>(data.get());
        return val->object;
    }
};

template<typename T>
ObjectHolder* std_create_vector()
{
    return new VectorHolder(new std::vector<T>);
}


int main()
{
    ObjectHolder* vh = std_create_vector < std::vector<float>>();
    // then later on you can get back the original type via:
    std::vector<float>* fp = vh->GetData<std::vector<float>*>();
}
```

Comment: ...Thanks for your answer. I  do appreciate it. But I notice on the function call it is `IGeneralVector* std_create_vectorf()`...That still doesn't seem to be 1 function for all the vector types..That just looks like one for float. Am I missing something here though?  I was just hoping to have a function...one that I maybe could give a `int type` sort of agrument or type it as its being used...I do prefer the former though...Thanks though, sorry if I was unclear but do you know of a solution?

Comment: You know what, I  really appreciate the time you spent on this so far. One little thing though, I did mention in my post it would have to go in an Extern C..so it can't be a template. . You have been so nice and I hate to put you out, but do you have  a solution to this issue pertaining to what I just said.  This would really answer A LOT of ?'s for me:)?